# Is this TK's real name?

Tags: angel-beats

> TK is a character in the well-known anime *Angel Beats!*

*Note:*

> **In the anime, TK's real name is never revealed.**

In he opening to the show, all of the characters are shown with their Japanese names in a speech bubble, and the English translation in the background.

TK's Japanese name is simply "TK", **but in the background of the speech bubble, there is something written in English.** (See the picture below)

[image]

(TK is on the far left.)

It looks to me that those letters say something like, "TH[???]"

Does anybody know what these letters are? And, do these letters signify TK's real name?

Comment: It says "THI KEI," phonetically "T.K." The other names have their respective romanization, e.g. 大山 is "OOYAMA."

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Oh well, I guess that would make sense...No hidden surprises here :-/